# Chocolatey install of dotnet failing

Tags: chocolatey

Executing :

> C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe install dotnetfx
> --fail-on-unfound --yes --no-progress --limit-output --allow-multiple --source enterprise-risk --timeout 2700 --version 4.8.20190930.20211014

But I am getting the error below and not sure why.  Any advice ?

"dotnetfx package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.",
"ERROR: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.",
"The install of dotnetfx was NOT successful.",

Comment: How did you get the dotnetfx package into your internal source? Did you use package internaliser?

Answer (score 0):

I had repackaged this to include the .exe in the package and not download it from the internet. When doing this with most Choco packages then I change the argument from Url to File.

The command being used in this package is 'Install-DotNetFramework' and not the usual 'Install-ChocolateyPackage'. 'File' isn't a valid argument for this command. Leaving it as 'Url' but still pointing to the packaged .exe worked fine.